# how to add 3d logo onto menu page in website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, graphics, bootstrap-4

I want to know the process taken to make menu page with a 3d logo like on this website: activetheory.net

Here's the screenshot of the menu page:
[image]

And also how the logo is moving according to the pointer location.

Comment: You have 7 questions in the site and for only one you have accepted the answer. Should really accept answers in all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish that effect, or similar to it: HTML5, JavaScript or Adobe Flash, to mention a few.

I believe that in the case of that page in specific, JavaScript was utilized.

You might want start here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_animate.asp

Once you master that, and basic JavaScript in general, you can start looking into Unity (https://unity3d.com)